# React Native conditional styling based on text returned by an API call

Tags: api, react-native, conditional-statements, styling

I am trying to apply conditional styling to text elements. The text values are extracted from a live API.

I have a train live status app that returns “Good Service”, “Minor Delays” and so on for each line. I would like to change the styling of the text based on the value. 
If it says “Good Service”, I will keep the text normal. 
If it says anything else, I would like to change it to red font.

Please see my Expo Snack prototype. 
https://snack.expo.io/@leourushi/api+conditional-styling

This is where I'm extracting the information for each train line from a live API. I'm using axios method to get all the lines ready before displaying them.

```
  async componentDidMount(){
    var request_1 = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/bakerloo/Status';
    var request_2 = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/central/Status';
    var request_3 = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/circle/Status';
    var request_4 = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/district/Status';
    var request_5 = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/hammersmith-city/Status';


  const [func1, func2, func3, func4] = await Promise.all([
    axios.get(request_1),
    axios.get(request_2),
    axios.get(request_3),
    axios.get(request_4)
  ]);

  const func5 = await axios.get(request_5);

  this.setState({
    dataSource: func1.data[0].lineStatuses,
    dataSource2: func2.data[0].lineStatuses,
    dataSource3: func3.data[0].lineStatuses,
    dataSource4: func4.data[0].lineStatuses,
    dataSource5: func5.data[0].lineStatuses,

    isLoading: false
  });
```

And I display the extracted strings here:

```
        <FlatList
          style={styles.rightColumn}
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.rightColumnText}>{item.statusSeverityDescription} </Text>}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id.toString()}
        />
```

The result typically says "Good Service", "Minor Delays" or other short phrases.

I want to change the styling of the text (styles.rightColumn) depending on the result returned by the API call. Is there a way to change styling so that it will behave as below?

If it returns "Good Service" = plain black font.

If it returns anything else = red font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this behavior by modifying your renderItem function as follows:

```
renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={[styles.rightColumnText, {color:  item.statusSeverityDescription == "Good Service" ? 'black' : 'red'}]}>{item.statusSeverityDescription} </Text> }
```

**Explanation:**

Here we are overriding our standard color depending on the value of `item.statusSeverityDescription`. If the status is not equal to "Good Service", we change the font color to red. BTW in this example we make use of the ternary operator.

```
style={[styles.rightColumnText, {color:  item.statusSeverityDescription == "Good Service" ? 'black' : 'red'}]}
```